# How to find ellipse with two points, angle and radii

Tags: geometry

I have the coordinates of two different points on the edge of an ellipse, and I have the $x$ and $y$ radius of the ellipse, and I have the angle of rotation for the ellipse. I'm fairly certain there are two possible resulting ellipses, but how do I go about finding their centers?

Comment: Clarification questions: By $x$ and $y$ radius do you mean the semimajor and semiminor axes? Do you know in advance that the $x$-axis is the semimajor axis, or could it be the semiminor axis?

Comment: yes and yes, the x is always the semimajor :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

HINT.- You have as data the equation $\frac{(x’)^2}{a^2}+\frac{(y’)^2}{b^2}=1$ where $a$ and $b$ are the radius of your ellipse, $x’$ and $y’$ being the new coordinates; you have also the angle of rotation $\alpha$ besides of two points of the ellipse  $(x_1,y_1)$ and $(x_2,y_2)$.

►Put $m=\tan \alpha$ and let $(h,k)$ the coordinates of the center.
The new axes are the lignes
$$\begin{cases}OX': y-k=m(x-h)\iff y-mx+mh-k=0\\[2ex]OY':y-k=\frac{-(x-h)}{m}\iff my+x-h-mk=0\end{cases}$$
►Let $P=(x,y)$ be a generic point in the ellipse; the corresponding coordinates $(x’,y’)$ in the new system are given by the distances of $P$ to the two new axes (the above lines).

It follows $$x'=\frac{my+x-h-mk}{\sqrt{1+m^2}}$$ $$y’=\frac{y-mx+mh-k}{\sqrt{1+m^2}}$$
►So you have $$\frac{(my+x-h-mk)^2}{(1+m^2)a^2}+\frac{(y-mx+mh-k)^2}{(1+m^2)b^2}=1\qquad (*)$$
►Now you can get two equations from $(*)$ by using the given points $(x_1,y_1)$ and $(x_2,y_2)$ of the ellipse. This allows the calculation of the coordinates $(h,k)$ of the center.

Comment: thanks for the detailed answer. I'm not sure I understand what _x_ and _y_ are in the equation though. _x1, y1_ and _x2, y2_ are the two points on the ellipsis that i mentioned in the question right? so what is _x,y_, you said that they are a "generic point in the ellipse" i don't understand that

Comment: to clarify where I'm coming from, I am a programmer, working on a renderer that can take the variables mentioned in the question (radii, rotation, 2 points on the edge) and return a center point (or 2), so at the end of the day i just need a h = ______ and a k = ______ and I'm not sure how to get there exactly from the equation provided above

Comment: $(x,y)$, it is a point arbitrary in the ellipse but whose coordinates are refered to the usual coordinate axes (in whose case the equation it is not in closest form, but in the form $(*)$. The only way I have found for you is that you can  get from $(*)$ a system of two equations with two unknowns,$h$ and $k$ using the two points you have as data.

Comment: thanks for the clarification, I actually figured out how to plug everything into mathematica, simplify (it returned quite a long couple of equations) and then output c code, and it seems to be working in my application. thanks so much for the help, I haven't done math like this since college and it was fun to dig back into this kind of stuff.